# Unable to add multiple potentiometer in Midi controller

Tags: controller, arduino, midi

I am building a simple arduino based midi controller to send cc midi messages, however I am able to send messages only through A0 (analog input).

Any help on this will be appreciated.

```c
#include <MIDI.h>
int pot[] = {A0,A1,A2};
int AnaPinsNum = 3;
int potIn[] = {0,0,0};
int analogValue = 0;

int lastAnalogValue[] = {0,0,0};


 void setup() 
 {
  MIDI.begin(4);
  // 115200 hairless MIDI
  Serial.begin(115200);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++);
 }
 void loop() {

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < AnaPinsNum; i++)

  potIn[i] = analogRead(pot[i])/8;

  // potentiometer could be too sensitive and
  // give different (+-1) values.
  // send CC only when the difference between last value
  // is more than 1
  if ((potIn[i]-lastAnalogValue[i]) > 1 || (potIn[i]-lastAnalogValue[i]) < -1) {
    // value changed?
    if (potIn[i] != lastAnalogValue[i]) {
      // send serial value (ControlNumber 1, ControlValue = analogValue, Channel 1)
      // more info: http://arduinomidilib.sourceforge.net/a00001.html
      MIDI.sendControlChange(1, potIn[i], 1);
      lastAnalogValue[i] = potIn[i];
    }
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not formatted correctly.

If you had used an editor that automatically indents the code, it would look like this:

```c
  for (i = 0; i < AnaPinsNum; i++)
      potIn[i] = analogRead(pot[i])/8;

  // potentiometer could be too sensitive and ...
  if ((potIn[i]-...) {
```

In other words, the `for` loop consists only of one line; all the following lines are executed after the loop has finished, and with the value of `i` being 3.

You forgot the braces around the loop body.

Comment: I am newbie in coding..didnt understand what exactly you mean..coz when I am compiling the code in Arduino IDE its not throwing any error..

Comment: I understood the braces and done that...now I am able to detect signal from other pots but its sending the same messages..I want to send different messages from different pot...with increment of values by 1 ...

Comment: If pot no1 is sending out Controller number 1 and channel number 1, 2nd pot should send Controller number 2 and channel no 2.. –

Comment: That is a different question. (Which could be answered with `i`.)